# Drawables with a space in the filename?

Tags: android, image, drawable

i'm developer an app that have more image (about 3000) that has space in filename like:

Im An image.jpg

being new to Android, I only found out now that are not accepted by the resources that have blank spaces or capital letters in the name, and this is a very big problem!

I use the same images in an application for iOS (without problems), and it would be almost impossible now to change all the names.

there is a way to solve this problem without renaming images?

if not, is there a way to quickly rename 3000 images?

thanks at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put them in the assets folder and use them fom there, but you will have to get each image as a bitmap without the possibility of using the R.drawable.image_name notation.

I use this method:

```
public static Bitmap getFoodImage(Context context, String foodType){
    InputStream bitmap = null;
    Bitmap bit = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 2;
    try {
        bitmap = context.getAssets().open(foodType.toUpperCase() + ".png");
        if(bitmap != null){

            DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int sWidth = metrics.widthPixels;

            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            Bitmap dBit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap, null, options);
            int intrinsicHeight = options.outHeight;
            int intrinsicWidth = options.outWidth;
            //int height = (int) (intrinsicWidth * proportion);
            int nHeight = (int) (intrinsicHeight/1.3);

            try {
                bitmap.reset();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("SGNAM", e.getMessage());
            }

            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

            dBit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap, null, options);

            Bitmap bP = Bitmap.createBitmap(dBit, 0, 0, intrinsicWidth, nHeight);

            if(sWidth < intrinsicWidth){
                bit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bP, intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight, false);
            }
            else{
                bit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bP, sWidth, intrinsicHeight, false);
            }
            bitmap.close();
            dBit = null;
            bP = null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bit;
}
```

As you can see i have all the image names in uppercase but you can skip that part if not needed (same for the png).

If you are in your onCreate method and the image you want is called An image.png (remember that in this example the .png is added by the method):

```
Context context = this;
Bitmap myBitmap = getFoodImage(context, An image);
```

You can set this bitmap as a resource for an imageView this way:

```
ImageView myImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

This should do he trick.

Comment: thanks for response, can you show me how get each image as a bitmap?

Comment: oh thank you! this process is fast in loading the image or not?

Comment: yeah it's pretty fast since I use it in a list view and it still works perfectly

Comment: i add this after onCreate in a Class?

Comment: yes, and then call it when you need an image passing a context and the image name.

Comment: ok, how to call this method from onCreate? like: getFoodImage(stringImage) ..?

Comment: thanks for your help, last thing: this method return a Bitmap, how pass bitmap to ImageView?

Comment: I just tried your solution and it works! only one thing not work.. i cannot add to assets image that have 'è' in name..

Comment: If it has been useful could you please set the answer as accepted?

Comment: yes yes i accept your answer of course, but there isn't solution for accented letters?

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't think there is a direct solution for that, is it to hard to rename the images that have accents?

Comment: This is not very fast - and things for the UI thread are supposed to be *very fast - and not at all memory efficient, just because you have incorrectly uses it in a listview does not mean it automatically becomes a good solution.

Comment: well it's good and fast enought for me, and it seem it solved at least part of Ilario's problem.

Comment: @NickCardoso i tried this method and work very well, i launch it from background thread and is fairly rapid, thanks again Ayoub

Comment: You are making an assumption there, but your answer should be downvoted, this is the most awful idea, creating not one but THREE bitmaps every time you load an image - on the ui thread no less-  rather than fix your broken naming convention and use the optimized proper method of loading resources

Comment: you are free to do as you want, this place is to answer other's questions a get the answer discussed, so you are welcome.

Comment: @NickCardoso I asked if there was a way, and Ayoub responded positively, showing how. this answer should be the most voted, for the simple reason that since this answer is true the other is wrong because it says you can not do. and your down vote does not make sense, because you have no reason to say that this answer is wrong or my question is wrong.

Comment: "get the answer discussed" exactly. That's why I've left the comment, so when other learners stumble across this they don't assume that this is a good solution because its the accepted answer. Because it absolutely isn't. This is a really bad idea that directly conflicts with android guidelines which you should have read. I'm not going to answer you any further on this.

Answer (score 5):

> there is a way to solve this problem without renaming images?

Nope. Res files can not have spaces.

Comment: thank for response, i edited my question, you can look at it?

Comment: Sure. What OS are you using?

Comment: I found this post for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662995/automator-script-to-rename-files-on-mac-os-x
So you would `find` " " and `replace` it with "_" or something.
Hope it helps.